# GTK Scrollbar Error

Tags: gtk

I'm using Lubuntu 13.10 and try to create a scrollable text-view. I copy the source code from the link below and run it, and I got a strange debug message when I use the scrollbar to scroll down. I didn't get the message if I don't use the scrollbar to scroll.

error message:
Gtk-Message: (for origin information, set GTK_DEBUG): failed to retrieve property `GtkRange::activate-slider' of type`gboolean' from rc file value "((GString*) 0x90672a0)" of type `GString'

source:
[GTK and scrolling text view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403731/gtk-and-scrolling-text-view)

my code:
http://pastebin.com/KnPY4jA0

debug message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bImaw.jpg

The program runs fine even though it display this debug message, but I hope to know what is causing this debug message and how to solve it.

Answer (score 6):

That happened to me using lubuntu 13.10. It fails to read a theme-related boolean value related to the sliders.

You have to locate the '`gtkrc`' file of the theme you're using and substitute the (I assume) textual boolean value with a '0' or a '1', depending on what you've got in the file, that is:

```
GtkScrollbar::activate-slider=FALSE
```

should be:

```
GtkScrollbar::activate-slider=0
```

I found the gtkrc file in `/usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`, so yours will probably be in `/usr/share/themes/***/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`. Check your desktop settings to find which theme you're using.